# Why is continue placed after yield return?

Tags: c#, return, yield, continue

I stumbled over this piece of code:

```
public IEnumerable<object> Process()
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {

        if (item.Created < DateTime.Now)
        {   
            yield return item;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me out understanding why `continue` isn't needless in this case (VS does not mark `continue` as a Redundant control flow jump statement)?

Comment: VS doesn't do alot of things.  I suspect running VS with say JetBrains Resharper installed would point out its redundant

Comment: Indeed VS isn´t smart enough to find this, however ReSharper gets the issue (tested on VS2010 and R# 2016)

Comment: Perhaps written by  someone new to the `yield` keyword in C#. Or someone trying to show how not to do stuff.

Comment: *why `continue` isn't needless in this case*. We can't. It *is* useless.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`yield return` will return an item as part of an enumerator. Once the calling method requests the next item, the code will restart on the line after the `yield return`.

In this particular case, the `continue` is redundant, as the loop will do no further work after that point anyway. But as a general application, it has plenty of uses.